# Error when using get() within @Composable (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to use the get() property within a @Composable function? I get an "unexpected token".

How do we use the set and get properties with compose?

```
val g:Int get()=88 // < works as expected outside @Composable

@Composable
fun Test() {
    val g:Int get()=88 // <  "unexpected token" error inside @Composable
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Backing properties are forbidden inside composeables because it stops Compose from updating when the `get()` results change and from caching the results for a repeated operation.

You should use `remember` variables. Learn more about [states in compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

Lets say your variable is computed depending on some other variables. Then, using `remember`, you can cache the result of that operation. You need to pass all the variables on which your `g` depends as keys to `remember`, so that it will only be computed once until one of the keys changes:

```
@Composable
fun TestView(a: Int = 44, b: Int = 2) {
    val g = remember(a, b) { a * b }
}
```

You can also use a [view model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state), but in that case you will be responsible for the view being recomposed with the new `g` values, for example by using mutable states for values that will change. Also in this case the calculations will not be cached.

```
class ScreenViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val a by mutableStateOf(44)
    val b by mutableStateOf(2)
    val g: Int
        get() = a * b
}

@Composable
fun TestView() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<ScreenViewModel>()
    viewModel.g
```